# Irreducible representations for the symmetry group $T_d$

Tags: matrix, group-theory

I am trying to get the explicit two dimensional irreducible representation matrices for the symmetry group $T_d$. I need the matrix representation for each element in the group. Are there any *Mathematica* packages or functions which will do this job? I know that for three dimensional representation I can use the function `"SpaceRepresentation"`.

Comment: `FiniteGroupData["Tetrahedral", "MatrixRepresentation"]`?

Comment: The package and articles at ["Noncommutative Algebra Package and Systems"](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4594/) might be of interest.

Comment: @J.M. FiniteGroupData will provide 4 dimensional representation. I am interested in getting two dimensional irreducible representation. I figured out that a similar problem has been resolved in the following link. But I am having issues in extending the same for the basis with of 2 dimension but with 3 variables. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/how-can-i-compute-the-representation-matrices-of-a-point-group-under-given-basis?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Does the tetrahedral group actually have a 2D representation? I can see 3D, but not 2D. (Admittedly, it has been a while since I did group theory.)

Comment: It has two 1D, two 3D and one 1D representation. Here is a quick reference: http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=902&option=4

Comment: I have a very strong misunderstanding and a question for the Community and Wolfram Team. Indeed, the operator `FiniteGroupData["Tetrahedral", "MatrixRepresentation"]` returns some 3D representation. But which representation is it? Indeed, the group Td has two 1D representations denoted as A1 and A2, one 2D representation denoted as E, and two 3D irreducible representations T1 and T2. One can have a look, for example, into the annex of the book W. A. Wooster, Tensors and Group theory... (Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1973) . Which one of the two do we get from Mma?

Comment: (Continuation)  **Two questions** arise 1. **Where are the other (that is, 1D and 2D) representations?** and 2. **Which one is the representation that one gets using `FiniteGroupData["Tetrahedral," "MatrixRepresentation"]`?** The same questions concern other crystallographic groups, for example, Oh. Please note that without such knowledge, the information obtained with the `FiniteGroupData` is not serious. It cannot be used for any responsible scientific work.

Comment: (Continuation 2) One cannot simply rely on such information. When we speak about the irreducible representation of any group its classification according to the standard international notation is a **must**. Otherwise, this is a childish play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:
(*Elements of the group Td**)
(*Four corners of the tetrhedra**)

```
{{1, 1, 1},   
{1, -1, -1},   
{-1, -1, 1},   
{-1, 1, -1},  
(*Four faces of the tetrahedra**)  
  (-1/3) {1, 1, 1},   
(-1/3) {-1, 1, -1},  
 (-1/3) {-1, -1, 1},     
(-1/3) {1, -1, -1}  
  };  
E0 = IdentityMatrix[3];  
C31 = RotationMatrix[120 Degree, (-1/3) {1, 1, 1}];  
C32 = RotationMatrix[120 Degree, (-1/3) {-1, 1, -1}];  
C33 = RotationMatrix[120 Degree, (-1/3) {-1, -1, 1}];  
C34 = RotationMatrix[120 Degree, (-1/3) {1, -1, -1}];  
C61 = RotationMatrix[240 Degree, (-1/3) {1, 1, 1}];  
C62 = C32.C32;  
C63 = C33.C33;  
C64 = C34.C34;  
C21 = RotationMatrix[180 Degree, {0, 0, 1}];  
C22 = RotationMatrix[180 Degree, {0, 1, 0}];  
C23 = RotationMatrix[180 Degree, {1, 0, 0}];  
r1 = ReflectionMatrix[Cross[{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}]];  
r2 = ReflectionMatrix[Cross[{1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}]];  
r3 = ReflectionMatrix[Cross[{1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1}]];  
r4 = ReflectionMatrix[Cross[{-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}]];  
r5 = ReflectionMatrix[Cross[{-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}]];  
r6 = ReflectionMatrix[Cross[{-1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}]];  
s1 = C23.r1;  
s2 = C22.r2;  
s3 = C21.r3;  
s4 = C22.r4;  
s5 = C23.r5;  
s6 = C21.r6;  
Td = {E0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, C31, C61, C32, C62, C33, C63, C34, 
   C64, C21, C22, C23, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6};  
f1[{x_, y_, z_}] := 2 z^2 - x^2 - y^2  
f2[{x_, y_, z_}] := Sqrt[3](x^2 - y^2)  
basis = {f1, f2};  
invTd = Inverse /@ Td;  
erep = SolveAlways[Flatten@Table[basis[[i]][invTd[[k]].{x, y, z}] == 
      Sum[basis[[j]][{x, y, z}] a[k, j, i], {j, 2}], {i, 2}, {k, 
      24}], {x, y, z}];    

MatrixForm /@ Table[a[k, i, j], {k, 24}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}] /. erep
```

Comment: You can use `Transpose[]` instead of `Inverse[]`, since the matrices involved are orthogonal. But, your multiplication should be using `.` (`Dot[]`) instead of `*` (`Times[]`).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for catching the error. Updated code will fetch the desired representation matrices.