# Are there irreducible representations of the crystallographic groups

Tags: group-theory

This yields the list of the irreducible representations of the point crystallographic group Oh:

```
FiniteGroupData[{"CrystallographicPointGroup",32}, "RepresentationNames"]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

**My question**:  is there a way to get these representations as matrices?

*Disclaimer*: I am aware of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117754/irreducible-representations-for-the-symmetry-group-t-d) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117754/irreducible-representations-for-the-symmetry-group-t-d) answers. In those answers, however, one builds the whole group from scratch, and then only makes the irreducible representations. My point is if there are the corresponding matrices already available?

Comment: `MatrixForm/@FiniteGroupData[{"CrystallographicPointGroup",32}, "MatrixRepresentation"]`?

Comment: @rhermans This is the vector irreducible representation built using the 3D basis  `{x,y,z}`. In the notation of the operation shown in my question its name is "Eu". But what about nine other irreducible representations?

Comment: @rhermans There was an error in my reply: it is the irreducible representation T1u, rather than Eu.